# CPU spikes every 30 frames animating PNG's with JavaFX using Timeline

Tags: java, animation, javafx, timeline

I am trying to use the `TimeLine` in JavaFX to display 450 PNG files quickly after each other, every 80ms would be best.  I can't even do it at 1.5 seconds.  The files are around 60kb each.  The files are read and stored in memory before the animation starts

**What happens:**

The GC runs every +-30 frames and the animation completely stops

**What I have tried:**

- Displaying the `SVGPath` of each image
- Converting the `SVGPath` to a PNG and displaying that in the original animation
- Reading the files into an `Image` object and storing in a PriorityQueue.  Populating a single `ImageView` on the screen with the different `Image` objects
- Reading the files into different `ImageView` objects, populating the screen with all of them with `setVisible(false)` and then when the animation runs I set only one to `setVisible(true)`
- Change the way the animation is created, last incarnation can be seen in this post
- Changing the cycleCount to unlimited or setting it to 1 and then starting the TimeLine every time.  Actually I need it to be 1 and start the TimeLine every time, because I need to do other things before I animated.  This is for my 3D printer so the printer might need to do something before it displays a layer and after it displays a layer.  The user can configure that
- I tried changing VM options (I have more than 10GB free mem):

  `-Xms10680m -Xmx10680m -XX:PermSize=1256m -XX:MaxPermSize=1256m -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSIncrementalMode -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -XX:+UseCompressedOops -XX:NewSize=1200m -XX:MaxNewSize=1200m`

-Upgraded the VM

**What next**

I am going to try viewport and see if that still spikes the CPU since it will be one large object, and just moving the view over it.  Hopefully it fixes the issue

**Running the app**

I start the app, load the model and before I start the animation the VM usage is sitting at 2.4GB, not at the specified 10GB.  When I start the app it buffers the images into the queue and the memory goes to 4.5GB, still not 10GB.  While the animation is running the memory increases to 5GB, actually fluctuates to just below and above 5GB

**Java version**

java version "1.8.0_40-ea"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_40-ea-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.40-b18, mixed mode)

**Upgraded Java version**

java version "1.8.0_40"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_40-b26)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.40-b25, mixed mode)

Now it stops at every 40 frames, not every 30 anymore

**GC log**

```
 CMS: abort preclean due to time 232.460: [CMS-concurrent-abortable-preclean: 1.017/97.038 secs] [Times: user=28.11 sys=2.54, real=97.04 secs] 
232.463: [GC (CMS Final Remark) [YG occupancy: 649460 K (1105920 K)]232.463: [Rescan (parallel) , 0.1360990 secs]232.599: [weak refs processing, 0.0000293 secs]232.599: [class unloading, 0.0278749 secs]232.627: [scrub symbol table, 0.0024514 secs]232.630: [scrub string table, 0.0006221 secs][1 CMS-remark: 1010091K(9707520K)] 1659552K(10813440K), 0.1735120 secs] [Times: user=0.66 sys=0.00, real=0.17 secs] 
232.637: [CMS-concurrent-sweep-start]
236.988: [GC (Allocation Failure) 236.988: [ParNew: 1105126K->122880K(1105920K), 0.5563841 secs] 2115195K->2064334K(10813440K), 0.5564532 secs] [Times: user=2.64 sys=0.66, real=0.56 secs] 
242.032: [CMS-concurrent-sweep: 0.760/9.395 secs] [Times: user=13.48 sys=1.01, real=9.39 secs] 
242.032: [CMS-concurrent-reset-start]
242.094: [CMS-concurrent-reset: 0.062/0.062 secs] [Times: user=0.09 sys=0.06, real=0.06 secs] 
246.489: [GC (Allocation Failure) 246.489: [ParNew: 1103611K->122880K(1105920K), 0.4099299 secs] 3045066K->2974070K(10813440K) icms_dc=6 , 0.4100021 secs] [Times: user=1.12 sys=1.36, real=0.41 secs] 
253.224: [GC (CMS Initial Mark) [1 CMS-initial-mark: 2851190K(9707520K)] 3454329K(10813440K), 0.0044382 secs] [Times: user=0.00 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs] 
253.229: [CMS-concurrent-mark-start]
255.071: [CMS-concurrent-mark: 1.842/1.843 secs] [Times: user=3.84 sys=0.02, real=1.84 secs] 
255.071: [CMS-concurrent-preclean-start]
255.103: [CMS-concurrent-preclean: 0.031/0.031 secs] [Times: user=0.03 sys=0.00, real=0.03 secs] 
255.103: [CMS-concurrent-abortable-preclean-start]
 CMS: abort preclean due to time 260.113: [CMS-concurrent-abortable-preclean: 1.737/5.011 secs] [Times: user=3.28 sys=0.05, real=5.01 secs] 
260.114: [GC (CMS Final Remark) [YG occupancy: 603138 K (1105920 K)]260.114: [Rescan (parallel) , 0.0107781 secs]260.125: [weak refs processing, 0.0000543 secs]260.125: [class unloading, 0.0321900 secs]260.157: [scrub symbol table, 0.0024284 secs]260.159: [scrub string table, 0.0005998 secs][1 CMS-remark: 2851190K(9707520K)] 3454329K(10813440K), 0.0517110 secs] [Times: user=0.09 sys=0.02, real=0.05 secs] 
260.166: [CMS-concurrent-sweep-start]
260.932: [CMS-concurrent-sweep: 0.767/0.767 secs] [Times: user=0.78 sys=0.02, real=0.77 secs] 
260.932: [CMS-concurrent-reset-start]
260.950: [CMS-concurrent-reset: 0.018/0.018 secs] [Times: user=0.02 sys=0.00, real=0.02 secs] 
264.709: [Full GC (System.gc()) 264.709: [CMS: 2850762K->3328314K(9707520K), 6.1267248 secs] 3453901K->3328314K(10813440K), [Metaspace: 27214K->27214K(1073152K)] icms_dc=2 , 6.1282785 secs] [Times: user=5.93 sys=0.16, real=6.13 secs] 
270.838: [GC (CMS Initial Mark) [1 CMS-initial-mark: 3328314K(9707520K)] 3341357K(10813440K), 0.0008962 secs] [Times: user=0.00 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs] 
270.839: [CMS-concurrent-mark-start]
282.708: [Full GC (System.gc()) 282.708: [CMS284.474: [CMS-concurrent-mark: 1.765/13.635 secs] [Times: user=4.57 sys=0.13, real=13.63 secs] 
 (concurrent mode interrupted): 3328314K->3328357K(9707520K), 7.6842704 secs] 3364891K->3328357K(10813440K), [Metaspace: 27270K->27270K(1073152K)] icms_dc=7 , 7.6858220 secs] [Times: user=9.39 sys=0.01, real=7.69 secs] 
302.308: [Full GC (System.gc()) 302.308: [CMS: 3328357K->3328494K(9707520K), 6.0054401 secs] 3362268K->3328494K(10813440K), [Metaspace: 27306K->27306K(1073152K)] icms_dc=7 , 6.0070951 secs] [Times: user=5.98 sys=0.02, real=6.01 secs] 
308.316: [GC (CMS Initial Mark) [1 CMS-initial-mark: 3328494K(9707520K)] 3328494K(10813440K), 0.0008023 secs] [Times: user=0.00 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs] 
308.317: [CMS-concurrent-mark-start]
320.308: [Full GC (System.gc()) 320.308: [CMS322.084: [CMS-concurrent-mark: 1.777/13.768 secs] [Times: user=4.10 sys=0.13, real=13.77 secs] 
 (concurrent mode interrupted): 3328494K->3328612K(9707520K), 7.1761016 secs] 3374259K->3328612K(10813440K), [Metaspace: 27340K->27340K(1073152K)] icms_dc=7 , 7.1777096 secs] [Times: user=8.91 sys=0.02, real=7.18 secs] 
339.108: [Full GC (System.gc()) 339.108: [CMS: 3328612K->3328734K(9707520K), 4.7149083 secs] 3381859K->3328734K(10813440K), [Metaspace: 27356K->27356K(1073152K)] icms_dc=7 , 4.7166533 secs] [Times: user=4.71 sys=0.00, real=4.72 secs] 
343.825: [GC (CMS Initial Mark) [1 CMS-initial-mark: 3328734K(9707520K)] 3338934K(10813440K), 0.0005971 secs] [Times: user=0.00 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs] 
343.826: [CMS-concurrent-mark-start]
355.908: [Full GC (System.gc()) 355.908: [CMS357.692: [CMS-concurrent-mark: 1.785/13.866 secs] [Times: user=4.26 sys=0.11, real=13.87 secs] 
 (concurrent mode interrupted): 3328734K->3328845K(9707520K), 6.5141915 secs] 3395891K->3328845K(10813440K), [Metaspace: 27376K->27376K(1073152K)] icms_dc=7 , 6.5157445 secs] [Times: user=8.25 sys=0.03, real=6.52 secs] 
374.308: [Full GC (System.gc()) 374.308: [CMS: 3328845K->3328969K(9707520K), 5.1376448 secs] 3399645K->3328969K(10813440K), [Metaspace: 27393K->27393K(1073152K)] icms_dc=7 , 5.1391948 secs] [Times: user=5.13 sys=0.00, real=5.14 secs] 
379.447: [GC (CMS Initial Mark) [1 CMS-initial-mark: 3328969K(9707520K)] 3339169K(10813440K), 0.0006191 secs] [Times: user=0.00 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs] 
379.448: [CMS-concurrent-mark-start]
391.907: [Full GC (System.gc()) 391.907: [CMS393.678: [CMS-concurrent-mark: 1.772/14.231 secs] [Times: user=4.31 sys=0.14, real=14.23 secs] 
 (concurrent mode interrupted): 3328969K->3329043K(9707520K), 7.0341647 secs] 3407161K->3329043K(10813440K), [Metaspace: 27454K->27454K(1073152K)] icms_dc=7 , 7.0357178 secs] [Times: user=8.75 sys=0.05, real=7.04 secs] 
411.910: [Full GC (System.gc()) 411.910: [CMS: 3329043K->3329171K(9707520K), 5.7665632 secs] 3426534K->3329171K(10813440K), [Metaspace: 27477K->27477K(1073152K)] icms_dc=7 , 5.7681657 secs] [Times: user=5.77 sys=0.00, real=5.77 secs] 
417.678: [GC (CMS Initial Mark) [1 CMS-initial-mark: 3329171K(9707520K)] 3329171K(10813440K), 0.0008204 secs] [Times: user=0.00 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs] 
417.679: [CMS-concurrent-mark-start]
```

**Queue populating**

I populate the queue using Executors

```
executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(LAYER_PRODUCERS);
for (int i = -0; i < totalLayers; i++) {
    layerProducer = new LayerProducer(queueImage, i);
    executorService.submit(layerProducer);
}
```

**Waiting for queue to fill then starting animation**

I wait for the threads to populate the queue and then I start the animation with Platform.runLater(), because it needs to run in the screen Thread

```
new Thread() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            while (true || executorService.isShutdown()) {
                Thread.sleep(1000);

                if (queueImage.size() >= (bufferSizeCalculated - 1)) {

                    break;
                }
            }

            Platform.runLater(() -> {
                runPrintThread();
            });
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(PrintingEngine.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}.start();
```

**Animation loop**

```
private void configureTimeLineContinuousNoBuildPlateMoveAnimation(Profile profile) {
    timeLocation = 0;
    List<KeyFrame> list = new ArrayList<>();
    ObservableList<KeyFrame> observableList = FXCollections.observableList(list);

    //create first frame
    KeyFrame firstKeyFrame = new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(timeLocation), (ActionEvent t) -> {
        GizmoSlice gizmoSlice = queueImage.poll();
        ImageView currentImageView = gizmoSlice.getFilledImage();
        currentImageView.setVisible(true);
        previousImageView = currentImageView;
        printEngineCallback.updateLog("Display Layer " + gizmoSlice.getName());
    });

    observableList.add(firstKeyFrame);

    for (int i = 0; i < totalLayers; i++) {
        //create a keyframe for each layer
        KeyFrame keyFrame = new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(timeLocation = timeLocation + projectionTime), (ActionEvent t) -> {
            previousImageView.setVisible(false);

            GizmoSlice gizmoSlice = queueImage.poll();
            ImageView currentImageView = gizmoSlice.getFilledImage();
            currentImageView.setVisible(true);
            previousImageView = currentImageView;
            printEngineCallback.updateLog("Display Layer " + gizmoSlice.getName());
        });

        observableList.add(keyFrame);

    }

    engineTimeLine = TimelineBuilder.create()
            .cycleCount(1)
            .keyFrames(list)
            .autoReverse(false).build();
}
```

**Test code**

I wrote a separate app that does this and the CPU doesn't spike at all.  So the code is probably fine and the VM is probably fine.  Not sure what the issue could be then.  Nothing else is running in the background, it is just a big JavaFX client application

```
package au.com.gizmo3dprinters;

import static au.com.gizmo3dprinters.Constants.GIZMO_SLICE;
import static au.com.gizmo3dprinters.Constants.TEMP_DIRECTORY;
import au.com.gizmo3dprinters.model.GizmoSlice;
import java.io.File;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.PriorityQueue;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javafx.animation.KeyFrame;
import javafx.animation.Timeline;
import javafx.animation.TimelineBuilder;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.util.Duration;

/**
 *
 * @author kobus
 */
public class FXMLDocumentController implements Initializable {
    private static final int BUFFER_SIZE = 1; //larger number is a smaller buffer
    private static final int LAYER_PRODUCERS = 3; //larger is more memory and cpu power

    private int totalLayers;
    private PriorityQueue<GizmoSlice> queueImage;
    private int projectionTime;
    private Timeline engineTimeLine;

    @FXML
    private ImageView sliceImageView;

    @FXML
    private Label label;

    @FXML
    private void handleButtonAction(ActionEvent event) {
        Comparator<GizmoSlice> comparator = new GizmoSliceComparator();
        double bufferSizeCalculated = totalLayers / BUFFER_SIZE;
        queueImage = new PriorityQueue(Double.valueOf(bufferSizeCalculated).intValue(), comparator);
        String gizmoName = "noname_1428817659204.gizmo";

        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(LAYER_PRODUCERS);
        for (int i = -0; i < totalLayers; i++) {
            LayerProducer layerProducer = new LayerProducer(queueImage, i, gizmoName);
            executorService.submit(layerProducer);
        }
        executorService.shutdown();
        try {
            executorService.awaitTermination(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(FXMLDocumentController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

        configureTimeLineContinuousNoBuildPlateMoveAnimation();
        engineTimeLine.playFromStart();
    }


    private void configureTimeLineContinuousNoBuildPlateMoveAnimation() {
        long timeLocation = 0;
        List<KeyFrame> list = new ArrayList<>();
        ObservableList<KeyFrame> observableList = FXCollections.observableList(list);

        //create first frame
        KeyFrame firstKeyFrame = new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(timeLocation), (ActionEvent t) -> {
            GizmoSlice gizmoSlice = queueImage.poll();
            System.out.println("display layer " + gizmoSlice.getLayer());
            Image currentImage = gizmoSlice.getFilledImage();
            sliceImageView.setImage(currentImage);
        });

        observableList.add(firstKeyFrame);

        for (int i = 0; i < totalLayers; i++) {
            //create a keyframe for each layer
            KeyFrame keyFrame = new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(timeLocation = timeLocation + projectionTime), (ActionEvent t) -> {
                GizmoSlice gizmoSlice = queueImage.poll();
                System.out.println("display layer " + gizmoSlice.getLayer());
                Image currentImage = gizmoSlice.getFilledImage();
                sliceImageView.setImage(currentImage);
            });

            observableList.add(keyFrame);

        }

        engineTimeLine = TimelineBuilder.create()
                .cycleCount(1)
                .keyFrames(list)
                .autoReverse(false).build();
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        // TODO
        totalLayers = 480;
        projectionTime = 400;
    }    

    class LayerProducer implements Runnable {

        private final PriorityQueue<GizmoSlice> queueImage;
        private boolean stop = false;
        private final int layer;
        private final String gizmoName;

        public void stopProducing() {
            stop = true;
        }

        public boolean isStopped() {
            return stop;
        }

        public LayerProducer(PriorityQueue<GizmoSlice> queueImage, int layer, String gizmoName) {
            this.queueImage = queueImage;
            this.layer = layer;
            this.gizmoName = gizmoName;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            String imageFilename = gizmoName + "fill" + layer + "." + GIZMO_SLICE + ".png";
            File imageFile = new File(TEMP_DIRECTORY + imageFilename);
            Image img = new Image(imageFile.toURI().toString());
            ImageView imageView = new ImageView(img);
            imageView.setVisible(false);

            GizmoSlice gizmoSlice = new GizmoSlice();
            gizmoSlice.setName(imageFilename);
            gizmoSlice.setFilledImage(img);
            gizmoSlice.setFilledImageView(imageView);
            gizmoSlice.setLayer(layer);
            queueImage.add(gizmoSlice);
        }
    }

    public class GizmoSliceComparator implements Comparator<GizmoSlice> {

        @Override
        public int compare(GizmoSlice x, GizmoSlice y) {
            Long layerX = x.getLayer();
            Long layerY = y.getLayer();

            return layerX.compareTo(layerY);
        }
    }

}
```

I am still working on this issue.

I changed the code to create a queue to read in the bytes of the images and then a second smaller queue that contained the bytes converted to images, but it was too much processing and too much memory.

I think I also figured out what my previous issue was with the CPU spikes.  I gave the VM 10GB of memory and the garbage collection caused problems.

I also tried off-heap memory, but all the tools need serialized objects.  I tried to serialize, but it was too slow.

I am now generating a movie from the image files using ffmpeg ([Generate video with ffmpeg to play using JavaFX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30437170/generate-video-with-ffmpeg-to-play-using-javafx/)), but I have not been able to figure out how to get ffmpeg to generate movies that JavaFX can display.  Last night I tried code to use VLC viewer in JavaFX and that displayed all generated videos.  Just don't like using OS specific code.  Also it is using 50% CPU with an 8 core i7 so it might not work on a Raspberry PI.  I need to do more tests to see if I can align the images of the movie with the images of the ImageView object

Comment: one of my first steps (I haven't looked deep into your code) would be to make sure that you get the production version of java 8u40, it looks like you're on a developer preview build. Many many of the updates lately have been towards memory optimization inside of the JVM, and it certainly won't hurt!

Comment: Since I can't figure out how to solve the problem I am splitting the app into two, the 3D world part and the printing part.  Seems there was alot happening in the app before.  Previously I used the Timeline to display layers for 200ms, now I display for 1300ms and it actually displays the same amount of time.  So 1000ms was used up by something else.  This is probably a better design anyway, now the 3D world can be used on a big PC and the printing can be used on a small PC connected to the printer

Comment: I believe the problem was because I was giving java 10GB of memory.  The garbage collector was causing most of my issues.